# Server crashes when switch to HTTPS

Tags: arcgis-server, ssl

We have a problem about ArcGIS Server 10.9. Our server works fine with port 6080 when we have HTTP as a protocol, but it crashes as soon as we put HTTP and HTTPS as protocol.

Server has problem with 6443 port machine status gets error "Error"

Failed to get the status of the server machine 'server.domain'. Could not connect to the ArcGIS component at URL 'https://server:6443/arcgis/admin/local/isAppServerStarted'. The ArcGIS component on that machine may not be running or the machine may not be reachable at this time.Error: Connection refused: connect
Code
500
we checked SSL certificate and it is not a problem with certificate.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: HTTPS has been the default for a long time. You should check that a firewall isn't blocking the port, or try using `localhost`, which is bound to a different address.

Comment: Please contact ESRI support. Likely an SSL configuration as certificates need to bind to HTTPS port 6443..

Comment: **Crash** is a strong word and I doubt is accurately describing the problem. Your encounter an error when trying to open the Server URL.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  There is nothing in your question that hints at a crash.

Comment: Is 'isAppServerStarted' a valid operation? 500 errors typically mean that you're doing something to ArcGIS server that it can't handle, such as using an operation that doesn't exist.